Adding the Azure Storage web resource to a form [no adx options listed]
I am creating a powerpages website that includes an upload form.
the upload form is setup to upload files to Azure Blob Storage since the uploaded files are quite large.
The connection between Azure blob storage and the upload form works as it should and the files do get uploaded.
The rest of the details of the upload form (e.g. name, email address) are saved to a table in Power Apps.
I am looking for way to correlate the uploaded files to the table entries. Microsoft is proving this solution detailed here to add a the azure storage web resource to a form.
step 2 states:

In the Add HTML web resource box, select adx_annotations/adx.annotations.html and choose Add.

I do not see the adx_annotations/adx.annotations.html option listed.
it mentions that

To see and interact with the file stored in Azure, you must add the
web resource adx.annotations.html to the form. As a pre-requisite,
ensure that your users have read access to adx_setting table.
Otherwise, the web resource won't render properly.

I checked and this is setup as needed.
What am I missing?


The web resource adx_annotations/adx.annotations.html is included with Power Pages installations that leverage the file attachment feature with Azure Blob Storage. If it's not visible, please check the following steps:

Verify Installation: Ensure that the required Power Pages solution and its dependencies are installed correctly in your environment. Check for any pending updates in the Power Platform Admin Center.
Search for the Web Resource:Navigate to Advanced Settings > Customizations > Customize the System > Web Resources.
Look for adx_annotations/adx.annotations.html.

If it's missing, it may not have been included during installation, or you might need to reinstall/repair the solution.
